# How to reclaim disk space of merged HFS+ partition?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, disk-space

On an external USB disk formatted with HFS+, I had merged a 800GB partition with a 2TB one. Now, although disk utility shows the merged partition as 2.8TB, the Finder only reports 2TB of space:
[image]

The partition table seems correct:

```
%diskutil list

/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Hermes                  2.8 TB     disk3s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS SkinTimeMachine         1.2 TB     disk3s3
```

```
%sudo gpt -vv -r show /dev/disk3

gpt show: /dev/disk3: mediasize=4000787030016; sectorsize=512; blocks=7814037168
gpt show: /dev/disk3: PMBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk3: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: /dev/disk3: Sec GPT at sector 7814037167
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640  5472071384      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  5472481024      262144         
  5472743168  2341031816      3  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  7813774984      262151         
  7814037135          32         Sec GPT table
  7814037167           1         Sec GPT header
```

I already tried first aid (fsck), which didn't reclaim anything. How can I make Finder recognise and use the added space?

Comment: yes, it only sees 2TB: 
`%df -h
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused               ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk3s2   1.8Ti  1.8Ti  1.3Gi   100%  489062          4294478217    0%   /Volumes/Hermes`

Comment: Yeah!  That did it: `diskutil resizeVolume /dev/disk3s2 R` (note the **R**, meaning _use all available space_). Feel free to formulate your comment as an anser, to reap the points.

Comment: The corollary question is: Why on earth does the Disk Utility app not do this (and indeed not offer to do it)?  Who wants a merged partition that doesn't use its space?

Comment: I had checked before with `diskutil resizeVolume /dev/disk3s2 limits` that all seemed correct, then I entered `diskutil resizeVolume /dev/disk3s2 R` to get the max size available, as per the man page: _You can grow a volume (partition) (back) to its maximum size possible, provided no new partitions have been created that are in the way, by specifying R for the new volume size. You should use R instead of attempting an absolute value such as 100% because the latter cannot count partition map overhead._

Comment: Post your comment as an answer. You will have to return later to accept your own answer.

Comment: Since I do not know how you merged, I can not really answer your corollary question. I can say the merge was not done correctly because the volume size was not the same as the partition size. Normally, the sizes would be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was this command which made the full merged partition size of 2.8TB available to the file system:

```
diskutil resizeVolume /dev/disk3s2 R
```

outputting

```
Resizing to full size (fit to fill)
[... log from fsck_hfs -fn -x /dev/rdisk3s2...]
Finished partitioning on disk3s2 Hermes
/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Hermes                  2.8 TB     disk3s2
```

As explained in the man page:

> *You can grow a volume (partition) (back) to its maximum size possible, provided no new partitions have been created that are in the way, by specifying R for the new volume size. You should use R instead of attempting an absolute value such as 100% because the latter cannot count partition map overhead.*

N.B.: This command shows the possible partition size limits:

```
diskutil resizeVolume /dev/disk3s2 limits
```

Thanks to [David Anderson](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/107222/david-anderson) for finding the answer.